# How to achieve complex messages using GWT i18n Messages interface

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I am trying to achieve the following string(s) format using GWT Messages but am not sure how to do it (or even if it can be done).

I have a Messages method signature like this:

`String organizedMessage(String username, String date);`

I have 2 arguments: username, date. Sometimes the username is null and sometimes the date is null but they are never both null at the same time.

Scenario #1: Username and Date both exist =
"Organized by [username] on [date]"

Scenario #2: Username exists but Date is null =
"Organized by [username]

Scenario #3: Username is null but date exists =
"Organized on [date]"

Can this be done with GWT Messages? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't think it can be done, only for plural count and enums you can specify mutliple messages for the same method. In this case you need to create 3 methods and do the testing on the variants in your own code.

Comment: Yea, that is what I am currently doing. I was hoping there was an undocumented 'trick' to make it work the way I wanted. Oh well.